# How to replace all "Ctrl" keys with "Command" keys in Android Studio Eclipse (windows) keymap?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.2

So I am using Android Studio in Mac. I changed Keymap to "Eclipse" which I am used to.

But now I want to replace all shortcuts which has "Ctrl" key with "Cmd" key.

I don't want to manually go to each shortcut and do this. 
how to do this simply?

Answer (score 11):

You can go to keymap settings (Preferences -> Keymap) and choose **Eclipse(Mac OS X)** from the **keymap** dropdown instead of choosing windows keymap.

Comment: Anyone needing help finding 'keymap', it's under Android Studio -> Preferences -> Keymap